# Regex options in Java String.matches()

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I want to add the option 'x' after my regex to ignore white space when using String.matches() in java. However, I see this on http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html:

> The Java String class has several methods that allow you to perform an
>   operation using a regular expression on that string in a minimal
>   amount of code. The downside is that you cannot specify options such
>   as "case insensitive" or "dot matches newline".

Does anyone have an easy way around this using java, so that I don't have to change my regex to allow zero or more white space in every spot there could be white space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way is to use [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class instead of just using the matches() method.

For example:

```
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher mtcher = ptn.matcher(myStr)
....
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the Pattern class, you can specify option flags as a second parameter to the `compile` method, as pointed out by Alvin:

```
Pattern.compile("[a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("Hello").matches() // true
```

However, this does not help us if the regex must be a string. When it's in a configuration file, for example. Luckily, there is another way

#### [Embedded Flag Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)

> It's also possible to enable various flags using embedded flag expressions. Embedded flag expressions are an alternative to the two-argument version of compile, and are specified in the regular expression itself.

```
Enter your regex: (?i)foo
Enter input string to search: FOOfooFoOfoO
I found the text "FOO" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "foo" starting at index 3 and ending at index 6.
I found the text "FoO" starting at index 6 and ending at index 9.
I found the text "foO" starting at index 9 and ending at index 12.
```

> The embedded flag expressions that correspond to Pattern's publicly accessible fields are presented in the following table:

```
Constant                    Equivalent Embedded Flag Expression
Pattern.CANON_EQ            None
Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE    (?i)
Pattern.COMMENTS            (?x)
Pattern.MULTILINE           (?m)
Pattern.DOTALL              (?s)
Pattern.LITERAL             None
Pattern.UNICODE_CASE        (?u)
Pattern.UNIX_LINES          (?d)
```

Comment: Good to know this is also possible. It would have made the implementation easier I presume and it is useful in situation when the only thing that is configurable from outside the Java-code is the regex. Thanks @stijn-de-witt !

Comment: @gsingh2011, I think this should be the accepted answer. The question is asking for an "easy way" and in many cases changing a few characters in the regex is the easiest option. The `Pattern` approach makes it explicit, but it may not be possible in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

I think the website you linked to is inaccurate. Look at the JavaDoc for the [multiline flag (m)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE), the [dot-all flag (s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), and the [comments flag (x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS).

Comment: I think the website is correct in the sense that you cannot set those flags through String class.

Comment: Perhaps technically correct, but misleading since it didn't tell readers that such functionality is available in the Pattern class as I pointed out. Thus, I think inaccurate is a fair description.